# HackerEarth Crazy kangaroo challenge

Tags: algorithm, c, programming-challenge, time-limit-exceeded

I want to find the lowest hop count from source to destination.
The [challenge](https://www.hackerearth.com/problem/algorithm/crazy-kangaroo/), in summary:

> The first line contains the number of test cases *T*, 1 ≤ *T* ≤ 100000.
>   The next *T* lines each contains three integers *A*, *B*, and *M*.  1 ≤ *A* ≤ *B* ≤ 10<sup>12</sup>.  1 ≤ *M* ≤ 10<sup>12</sup>.
>
> For each test case, print the number of multiples of *M* that are in the range [*A*, *B*] (inclusive).

My output is correct but the execution time of my program is like 1.0015 seconds when given 100000 entries. But I need to do the program within 1 second time frame. I have tried a lot to reduce the execution time but couldn't. Can anybody help me to achieve an execution time within 1 sec.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    unsigned int n, i, j, k, h,count=0,l=0;
    scanf("%u", &n);
    for (i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        scanf("%u %u %u", &j, &k, &h);
        l=j;
        count = 0;
        while(l<=k)
        {
          if(l%h==0)
          {
            count=count+1;
          }
          l++;
        }
        printf("%u\n", count);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

sample input-> 1 10 2

sample output-> 5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Data declarations

Your [data types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types) are not large enough.  By the C standard, an `int` is only guaranteed to hold up to 32767, which is smaller than 100000.  Similarly, an `int` could be insufficient to hold the values of *A*, *B*, and *M*.  You'll need a `long long` or `int64_t`.

A big block of declarations like this is not ideal:

> ```
> unsigned int n, i, j, k, h,count=0,l=0;
> ```

- You should declare variables as close to the point of use and in as tight a scope as possible.
- Single-character names are cryptic.

### Algorithm

You don't have to simulate a kangaroo, counting hops, to answer these questions.  The answer will be roughly

$$\frac{B - A}{M}$$

… except that you have to take care of fencepost (off-by-one) errors at the edges.  I'll leave it to you to figure out the details.